# How to provide mobile app access to view the App located in different tenant?

Tags: powerbi

The provider has created Power BI report, and added it into an app.

I am added as a guest user to the provider's Azure Tenant.

The app has been published and my account (guest account) has been given appropriate permissions.

I can access the app via link in the browser.

How do I access this app via the Power BI mobile app?

Comment: Which login are you using in the mobile app? You own PBI or the guest account?

Comment: I have installed the Power BI Mobile app on my phone. I have logged in using my own username(email)/password, this takes me to my tenant. From here, how do I access the app that is shared with me in the provider's tenant?